# Modify gradient drawable to only extend 70% of height

Tags: android, android-drawable

I have the following gradient drawable which I'm using to create a divider/right border between my FragmentTabHost tabs:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <gradient
        android:angle="180"
        android:startColor="#fff"
        android:centerColor="@android:color/transparent"
        android:centerX="0.01" />
</shape>
```

It works fine, but I would like it's height to only be 70% of the overall height of the tabs, and to be vertically centered. How can I do this?

Comment: could you use padding to approximate what you want?            <padding android:top="20dp" android:bottom="20dp" />

Comment: Tried this but it doesn't affect the height of the right border. It actually removes the text from the tabs instead.

Comment: Maybe I could use a 9 patch drawable to do the trick?